# Maximally connected planar graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a planar graph. Is it true that:

(1) $G$ is a subgraph of a maximally connected planar graph.

(2) If $G$ is a maximally connected planar graph with more than four vertices, then all vertex has degree at least 3.

Comment: How do you define "maximally connected planar graph"? What have you tried e.g. did you try to draw any basic examples?

Comment: @dtldarek: Thanks for replying! A planar graph is called maximally connected if adding any edges to the graph will make it nonplanar. Actually, I draw some pictures and convinced myself that this is true. For the vertex that is "inside" the graph, one can simply complete it so that they are all triangles, for the exterior ones, seems that I can draw the pictures so that the process would stop: there will then be only two "exterior" vertex.

Comment: This is my first 30 minutes in graph theory, so please forgive me for knowing almost no terminology.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- If you have a non-maximal planar graph, then you can make it maximal planar by adding edges. For the exterior face, just treat it as ordinary face, and then turn it inside out.
- Sometimes it is beneficial to think of planar graphs embedded not in a plane, but in a sphere (it's the same). In such a way, you can pick any face of the graph, and make it an outer face by stretching the graph.
- Prove that if a vertex has degree $< 3$ then you can always add an edge (if you have enough spare vertices, this is where the $n \geq 4$ assumption is needed), there are three cases (degrees 0, 1 and 2) all of them simple, just draw them all out.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! With the "sphere" point of view it seems that the result can be poof quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: G is 2 vertices connected by 1 edge.

(Assuming we're not working with multi-graphs.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed I forgot to mention that the graph has at least four vertice. I will edit the question.

Comment: All of $K_1$, $K_2$ and $K_3$ work here (without the $n \geq 4$ assumption).